# Wait for executed AsyncTask with ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, intentservice

I have a method `public void writeEntry(Activity ctx, Entry entry)` which get some data and have to call a native method, which takes longer to finish.
So I created an *AsyncTask* which handles the *ProgressDialog* and the native method. It works great in an own *Activity* to test it, in that *Activity* I used a callback interface and so on.

In my case I have the above described method and have to execute the *AsyncTask*. The executing can't be in that method because it doesn't halt the further execution.
I need the result from the native method before I can continue with the execution.
Is there any possibility to wait for the *AsyncTask* til it is finished? The method `wait()` isn't an option because the UI Thread will wait, too and so the sense of a *ProgressDialog* will be lost.

Can I use the method `runOnUiThread()` from the given parameters or is the only solution to start an own *Activity*?

Comment: there, where? I am confused about Activity description. Could you please write names rather using "there" so we know how many different activity we are looking at, thanks else just dump related codes in your question :)

Comment: I have edited the Q. I hope it is now clear. In general there is only the main *Activity*, which calls the method `writeEntry()`.

Comment: I tried to understand it, So basically you have wrtieEntry method which executes AsyncTask but that(writeEntry) code execution keeps continuing. But you want that code to wait until asynctask finish it's job. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. I think the AsyncTask isn't the right choice for it.

Comment: Well the whole concept of having AsyncTask is to keep your current thread running and do some process at background, What I will suggest is in my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first solution was to use callback methods with an interface implementation see the example https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396376/390177.

After chatting a while in the Android chat I heard that there is a more praticable solution.
You can use of an *IntentService* in combination with a *PendingIntent*.
The communication is realized with *Intent*'s.
If you want to use a *ProgressDialog*, you need an own *Activity* for it, which register for example a *BroadcastReciever* and the *IntentService* sends it actual status per Broadcast.

But lets start now.
First we create the *Activity*, which contains the *ProgressDialog* and a registered *BroadcastReceiver*. The *BroadcastReceiver* listen for messages about updating and finishing the dialog.

For the *Activity* we needs the layout ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000">
</LinearLayout>
```

... and the related code:

```
public class ProgressActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * ProgressDialog which is shown
     */
    private ProgressDialog progessDialog_g;

    /**
     * Instance of the BroadcastReceiver
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver_g;

    /**
     * Identifier for the different settings of the ProgressDialog
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_HORIZONTAL_BAR = "pbar_horizontal_bar";
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_CANCELABLE = "pbar_horizontal_cancelable";
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_STR_MESSAGE = "pbar_message";
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_MAX = "pbar_max_bar";
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_VALUE = "pbar_value";
    protected static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_MAX_VALUE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.progress);

        progessDialog_g = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // Reads and sets the settings for the ProgressDialog
        Intent i = getIntent();
        progessDialog_g.setCancelable(i.getBooleanExtra(
                PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_CANCELABLE, false));
        if (i.getBooleanExtra(
                PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_HORIZONTAL_BAR, false)) {
            progessDialog_g.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        } else {
            progessDialog_g.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        }
        progessDialog_g
                .setMessage(i
                        .getStringExtra(PROGRESS_DIALOG_STR_MESSAGE));
        progessDialog_g.setMax(i.getIntExtra(
                PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_MAX, 100));

        // Create the IntentFilter for the different broadcast messages
        IntentFilter iFilter =
                new IntentFilter(
                        ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_INIT);
        iFilter.addAction(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_UPDATE);
        iFilter.addAction(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH);

        // Creates the BroadcastReceiver
        receiver_g = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                Log.d(DefaultPreferences.DEBUG_PREFIX + "ProgressActivity",
                        intent.getAction());

                if (ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_INIT
                        .equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    // Sets the ProgressDialog style
                    if (intent
                            .getBooleanExtra(
                                    PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                                    false)) {
                        progessDialog_g
                                .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    } else {
                        progessDialog_g
                                .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    }

                    // Shows the ProgressDialog    
                    progessDialog_g.show();
                } else if (ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_UPDATE
                        .equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    // Updates the ProgressDialog
                    int value =
                            intent.getIntExtra(
                                    PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_VALUE,
                                    -1);
                    if (value != -1) {
                        progessDialog_g.setProgress(value);
                    }
                } else if (ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH
                        .equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    // Finishs the ProgressDialog
                    progessDialog_g.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        // Registers the BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(receiver_g, iFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        unregisterReceiver(receiver_g);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Now we want to use the *Activity*, so lets start with calling it:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(parentActivity, <packages>.ProgressActivity);
i.putExtra(ProgressActivity.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_CANCELABLE, cancelable_g);
i.putExtra(ProgressActivity.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_HORIZONTAL_BAR, showProgress_g);
i.putExtra(ProgressActivity.PROGRESS_DIALOG_STR_MESSAGE, message_g);
i.putExtra(ProgressActivity.PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_MAX, ProgressActivity.PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_MAX_VALUE);

parentActivity.startActivity(i);
```

So we habe a running ProgressActivity, which waits for different broadcasts. But first we need the *IntentService*, which sends the broadcasts.
So lets go:

```
public class ExampleProgressService extends IntentService {
    /**
     * PendingIntent for callback.
     */
    protected PendingIntent pi_g = null;

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "ExampleProgressService";

    /**
     * Message identifier for ProgressDialog init
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_INIT = "Dialog.Progress.Init";
    /**
     * Message identifier for ProgressDialog finish
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH = "Dialog.Progress.Finish";
    /**
     * Message identifier for ProgressDialog update
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_UPDATE = "Dialog.Progress.Update";

    /**
     * Identifier of the result for intent content
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT = "Result";
    /**
     * Identifier of the result error for intent content
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Result.Error.Message";
    /**
     * Identifier of the result error exception for intent content
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_ERROR_EXCEPTION = "Result.Error.Exception";
    /**
     * Identifier of the result status for intent content
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_STATUS_BOOL = "Result.Status.boolean";

    /**
     * Identifier of the pending intent for intent content
     */
    public static final String PROGRESS_DATA_PENDING_RESULT = "PendingResult";

    public ExampleProgressService() {
        super("ExampleProgressService");
    }

    /**
     * Send the finish message.
     */
    private void closeProgressActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Do some magic with the intent content
     */
    private void extractVariablesFromIntentAndPrepare(Intent intent)
            throws Exception {
        pi_g = (PendingIntent) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(PROGRESS_DATA_PENDING_RESULT);

        if (pi_g == null) {
            throw new Exception("There is no pending intent!");
    }

    /**
     * Sends an error message.
     */
    private void failed(Exception e, String message) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_ERROR_EXCEPTION, e);
        i.putExtra(PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_ERROR_MESSAGE, message);

        send(i, false);
    }

    /**
     * Sends the init message.
     */
    private void initProgressActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_INIT);

        intent.putExtra(PROGRESS_DIALOG_BOOL_HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                multipart_g);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.IntentService#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        extractVariablesFromIntentAndPrepare(intent);

        initProgressActivity();

        // do your calculation here and implements following code
        Intent intent = new Intent(PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_UPDATE);

        intent.putExtra(PROGRESS_DIALOG_INT_VALUE, progressValue);

        sendBroadcast(intent);

        // If you finished, use one of the two methods to send the result or an error
        success(result);
        failed(exception, optionalMessage);
    }

    /**
     * Sends the data to the calling Activity
     */
    private void send(Intent resultData, boolean status) {
        resultData.putExtra(PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_STATUS_BOOL, status);

        closeProgressActivity();

        try {
            pi_g.send(this, Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,
                    "There is something wrong with the pending intent", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends the result message.
     */
    private void success(String result) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT, result);

        send(i, true);
    }
}
```

The result of the calculation progress shall be available in the **parentActivity**, so we create the *PendingIntent* in that *Activity* and call the *IntentService*.

```
// Some identifier for the call
int requestCode = 12345;

final Intent sI = new Intent(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_SERVICE_ACTION);

// Callback
sI.putExtra(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DATA_PENDING_RESULT, parentActivity
        .createPendingResult(requestCode, null,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

// Service start
parentActivity.startService(sI);
```

For receiving the results, we have to override the method `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // Compares the requestCode with the requestCode from above
    if (requestCode == ...) {
        if (data.getBooleanExtra(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_STATUS_BOOL, false)) {
            // Calculation was success
            data.getStringExtra(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT);
        } else
        {
            // Calculation is failed
            data.getStringExtra(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ((Exception) data.getSerializableExtra(ExampleProgressService.PROGRESS_DATA_RESULT_ERROR_EXCEPTION));
        }
    }
}
```

That was the magic, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

so I will try to explain as much as I can

Start your heavy process inside an AsyncTask, but whatever code you want to execute after completion of AsyncTask put it in a separate public method. Now once you finish with your heavy process call that separately created method in `onPostExecute()`.

So psuuedo code will look like this,

```
class main extends Activity {

    class Something extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Start your progress bar...
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Do your heavy stuff...
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // close your progress dialog and than call method which has
            // code you are wishing to execute after AsyncTask.
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this will help,

Good Luck!

Comment: How can I wait with that code fragment for result of the *AsyncTask* without freezing the UI Thread?